# How to get list of permissions in Yii2?

Tags: php, permissions, yii2

I need somehow to get the list of existing permissions in my Yii2 application. 
yii/rbac/DbManager as authManager is used.
And when trying to run:

```
$permissions = Yii::$app->authManager->getPermissions();
```

I receive list in which are permissions and routes:

```
Array ( [/admin-tools/*] => yii\rbac\Permission Object ( [type] => 2 [name] => /admin-tools/* [description] => Access admin-tools [ruleName] => [data] => [createdAt] => 1500542371 [updatedAt] => 1500542371 ) [/admin/*] => yii\rbac\Permission Object ( [type] => 2 [name] => /admin/* [description] => access admin extension [ruleName] => [data] => [createdAt] => 1500541632 [updatedAt] => 1500541632 )  [/group] => yii\rbac\Permission Object ( [type] => 2 [name] => /group [description] => [ruleName] => [data] => [createdAt] => 1502190828 [updatedAt] => 1502190828 )  ) [permission_admin] => yii\rbac\Permission Object ( [type] => 2 [name] => permission_admin [description] => [ruleName] => [data] => [createdAt] => 1500559417 [updatedAt] => 1502190927 ) [permission_hr] => yii\rbac\Permission Object ( [type] => 2 [name] => permission_hr [description] => [ruleName] => [data] => [createdAt] => 1500559479 [updatedAt] => 1500559919 ) )
```

I suppose there is another smarter way to get this data. Because yii2-admin module is able to get list of only permissions, but I don`t have any idea how to do this?.

Answer (score 2):

The resulting

```
$permissions = Yii::$app->authManager->getPermissions();
```

is an array with all the permissions object content

if you need  only name   and description you can iterate  over the array  eg:

```
  $permissions = Yii::$app->authManager->getPermissions();
  foreach($permissions as $key => $perm){
    echo 'name : ' . $perm->name . ' description : ' . $perm->description . <br />;
    echo 
  }
```

you can check yii2 doc http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rbac-dbmanager.html

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rbac-basemanager.html#getPermissions()-detail

could b you are looking for  `getPermissionsByUser()`

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rbac-dbmanager.html#getPermissionsByUser()-detail